# How to toggle hashtags on blog posts individually by button on each blog post with same classname (vanilla js)

Tags: javascript, html, tumblr

I have a div/button under each blog post-text to toggle the display of the tags/categories it is filled under. My understanding of JS is *very* limited. These two pieces of js is what I have but both gives the same result: clicking any of the toggle-buttons on any blog post only displays the first blog posts' tags. (this is on Tumblr btw)

```
//------ first option
var toggleTags = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle-tags");

for (var i = 0; i < toggleTags.length; i++) {
    toggleTags[i].addEventListener("click", showTags);
}
function showTags(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < toggleTags.length; i++) {
        var activateTags = document.querySelector(".tags");
        activateTags.classList.toggle("tags-active");
    }
}

//------ or this one
const tagButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle-tags");
for (const button of tagButtons) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        const activateTags = document.querySelector(".tags");
        activateTags.classList.toggle("tags-active");
    });
}
```

Given my lack of knowledge, I couldn't find an answer on here that I could apply myself, so I'm coming up short and I've absolutely no idea how to fix this myself. `.tags` is set to `display:none;` and `.tags-active` set to `display:block!important;`

This is the structure of each blog post in case that's of any use:

```
<article class="post">
    <div class="post-content text">
        post body
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        <div class="info-content">
            <div class="right">
                <div class="toggle-tags">toggle tags</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tags">
            <a href="#">text</a>
            <a href="#">quotes</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your code is that `const activateTags = document.querySelector(".tags");` will select the first element with the class `.tags`. So you are toggling the class only on that one. You need to iterate through them accordingly as you do with your buttons. Check the snippet.

```js
const tagButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle-tags");
const activateTags = document.querySelectorAll(".tags");
tagButtons.forEach((button, index) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    activateTags[index].classList.toggle("tags-active");
  });
});
```

```css
.tags{
  display:none
}

.tags-active{
  display:block!important;
}
```

```html
<article class="post">
  <div class="post-content text">
    post 1
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="info-content">
      <div class="right">
        <div class="toggle-tags">toggle tags</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags">
      <a href="#">text</a>
      <a href="#">quotes</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
<article class="post">
  <div class="post-content text">
    post 2
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="info-content">
      <div class="right">
        <div class="toggle-tags">toggle tags</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags">
      <a href="#">text</a>
      <a href="#">quotes</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
<article class="post">
  <div class="post-content text">
    post 3
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="info-content">
      <div class="right">
        <div class="toggle-tags">toggle tags</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tags">
      <a href="#">text</a>
      <a href="#">quotes</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

I select all the `activetags` using `querySelectorAll` and choose the appropriate one to the clicked button using `index`.

Comment: brilliant, thank you! I actually get this, awesome.